# Will Jigsaw and Penrose projects be preferable to Felix. Karaf?

Tags: osgi

I have been reading up the modularity features lined up for Java 9 - namely Jigsaw and Penrose projects. I'm keen to hear whether anyone with experience in OSGI thinks Java 9 will become the de facto runtime for projects that once looked to using frameworks like Felix and Karaf?

Comment: Not a chance in hell. But this is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you look close at Jigsaw you will see that at that incarnation it will not be useful for applications because it lacks some fundamental features to make it useful (that is one reason why it is delayed again). Look at for example annotation scanning support.

Additionally, Jigsaw only provides a minimal module system that is not much more than an extra access level. OSGi provides a wealth of features that are simply not in scope for Jigsaw.

Comment: Out of interest: Can you elaborate or provide a link what the issue is with annotation scanning support?

Answer (score 0):

the modularity in java9 is resolved at compile time.
you define modules and their dependencies. Then you compile and bind the packages together to get an ad hoc JVM.
With OSGi (karaf, felix, equinoxe ...) the resolution is dynamic it is done at runtime. either when the module is deployed (import) or when it is executed (dynamic-import).

both are not contradictory but complementary.
One can very well imagine a karaf written in the form of java9 modules to obtain a minimal kernel. the dynamic additions of OSGi being relegated to the runtime.

I think an evolution of OSGi will have to decide the interpretation to be made when deploying java9 modules in a container.
the module header contains the inport / export information, but no version concept. just like today when a bundle imports a package without specifying a version, it is the most available version that is bound.

A+JYT